# Multiple flatMaps in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

Instead of `xs map f map g` it's more efficient to write `xs map { x => g(f(x)) }`, and similarly for multiple `filter` operations.

If I have two or more `flatMap`s in a row, is there a way to combine them into one, that's maybe more efficient? e.g.

```
def f(x: String) = Set(x, x.reverse)
def g(x: String) = Set(x, x.toUpperCase)

Set("hi", "bye") flatMap f flatMap g  
  // Set(bye, eyb, IH, BYE, EYB, ih, hi, HI)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to do such a transformation, we need to use some identity the operations have. For example, as you wrote, `map` has the identity

```
map f ∘ map g ≡ map (f ∘ g)
```

(where `∘` stands for function composition - see [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1).compose(...); and `≡` stands for an equivalence of expressions). This is because classes with `map` can be viewed as [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor), so any reasonable implementation of `map` must preserve this property.

On the other hand, classes that have `flatMap` and have a way how to create some kind of one-element instance (like creating a singleton `Set`) usually form a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29). So we may try to deduce some transformations from the monad rules. But the only identity we can deduce for repeated applications of `flatMap` is

```
(set flatMap f) flatMap g ≡ x flatMap { y => f(y) flatMap g }
```

which is a kind of [associativity relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associativity) for `flatMap` composition. This doesn't help much for optimizing the computation (actually it can make it worse). So, the conclusion is, there is no similar general "optimizing" identity for `flatMap`.

The bottom line is: Each function given to `Set.flatMap` creates a new `Set` for each element it's applied to. We cannot avoid creating such intermediate sets unless we completely forget using composing `flatMap` and solve the problem in some different way. Usually this is not worth, since composing `flatMap`s (or using `for(...) yield ..`) is much cleaner and more readable, and the little speed trade-off isn't usually a big issue.

Answer (score 5):

In [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/) there is a way to compose functions like `a -> m b` and `b -> m c` into `a -> m c` (like the function here, from `String` to `Set[String]`). They are called [Kleisli functions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrow_tutorial#Kleisli_Arrows), by the way. In haskell this is done simply with `>=>` on those functions. In scala you'll have to be a bit more verbose (by the way, I've changed the example a bit: I couldn't make it work with `Set`, so I've used `List`):

```
scala> import scalaz._, std.list._
import scalaz._
import std.list._

scala> def f(x: String) = List(x, x.reverse)
f: (x: String)List[String]

scala> def g(x: String) = List(x, x.toUpperCase)
g: (x: String)List[java.lang.String]

scala> val composition = Kleisli(f) >=> Kleisli(g)
composition: scalaz.Kleisli[List,String,java.lang.String] = scalaz.KleisliFunctions$$anon$18@37911406

scala> List("hi", "bye") flatMap composition
res17: List[java.lang.String] = List(hi, HI, ih, IH, bye, BYE, eyb, EYB)
```

Comment: +1 just for introducing Kleisli functions. But is this actually faster? Or at least reasonably expected to be faster. I find it really hard to estimate performance for scalaz magic.

Comment: Yeah, I believe, it is not any faster. It uses a `Bind` instance for `List`, specifically, it's `bind` method, which is essentially a `flatMap`. So, there is a second `flatMap` hidden in this code.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you describe for filters basically skips the creation of intermediate collections.

With `flatMap` at least the inner collections get created inside the functions, so I can't imagine any way to skip that creation without changing the function.

What you could try is using a view, although I'm not sure if this does anything usefull with flatMap.

Alternatively you could build a `multiFlatMap` which builds the final collection directly from the function results, Without stuffing the intermediate collections returned from the functions in a new collection.

No idea if this is workable. I at least see some serious type challenges comming, since you would need to pass in a Seq of functions where each function returns a Collection of A where A is the input type for the next function. At least in the general case of arbitrary types and arbitrary number of functions this sound somewhat challenging.